# Autolayout to place 4 views with same width

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints

[image]

I am using Autolayout. I would like to set a views height to be equal to another view's width. The width of brown view is set as 0.3 proportional to its parent view and height of green view should be same as width of brown view.
i have done setting constraints to 4 views but width of 4 views is not same

kindly refer the image.

Answer (score 0):

**Obj-c**

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:greenView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:brownView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
    multiplier: 1
    constant:0];
```

**Swift**

```
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: greenView, 
                    attribute: .Height, 
                    relatedBy: .Equal,
                    toItem: brownView,
                    attribute: .Width, 
                    multiplier: 1, 
                    constant: 0.0);
```

*I didn't test the code so let me know if it has problems*

Comment: hello , i applied the same constraint that you have mentioned to green view but the result is the image that i shared before. as you can see height of green view and width of brown view is not same

Answer (score 0):

Here Ctrl drag from your `greenView` to `brownView` and set constraint of `Equal Width`. After that select the `Equal Width` constraint and set the First Item as your `greenView.height` [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vtjx.png) and finally set the width, X and Y position for your `greenView`.